# Python Server in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web, web.py

I have written some Web services in Python.I want to deploy it in AWS, I have created the instance.
I tried to run using putty and it was coming up well using the command `python Flo.py`, which starts the server 0.0.0.0:8080. But the problem is when I close the putty window the server is terminating. How i can start a server in 8080 just like httpd?

All helps are invited

Comment: `nohup python Flo.py &`

Comment: what operating system is on the instance?

Comment: @Reut Sharabani: Server is in Ubuntu

Comment: Use python gunicorn which works on concept of background processes and run your app on server using gunicorn as a deamon process in background. http://gunicorn.org/#docs i have done it its really easy or either you can use conventional screen as stated below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **highly recommend** you use [`screen`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) (or [`tmux`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux)). And you may want to use [`upstart`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) as well.

---

### Screen:

> Screen is a full-screen window manager that multiplexes a physical terminal between several processes (typically interactive  shells).

`tmux` and `screen` are doing the same thing - which is terminal multiplexing. This will give you a terminal you can attach to and disconnect from to keep it running when you're not on the server.

To test it simply install using:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Now use the following to open a screen terminal under the name `my_screen`, running your script as it starts:

```
screen -dmS my_screen python Flo.py
```

And attach to it using:

```
screen -r my_screen
```

Detach using `ctrl+A` followed by `ctrl+D`, and now you can leave the server (screen will keep running with the process in it)

Read more [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen).

---

### Upstart:

> Upstart is an event-based replacement for the /sbin/init daemon which handles starting of tasks and services during boot, stopping them during shutdown and supervising them while the system is running.

Upstart is the new way to start services on debian as soon as the system starts.

To add an upstart service you need to add a configuration file under `/etc/init` (open one of the files there and see an example).

These files can be extremely simple so don't be intimidated by what you see there.

You can make a service to run your server / service and send output to a log file which you can then use to keep track of what's happening.

Read more [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).